# No available authentication scheme in burp suit

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, burp

I were working with Burp Suit then suddenly it's stopped and occurred an error:

> The client failed to negotiate a TLS connection to google.com:443: No available authentication scheme

This message keep showing when I tried to open **any websites** via Burp Suit, I also receive an error on browser's screen too (Internet is connected and all the sites are available and accessible when I turn off Burp Suit's proxy):

[image: Connection error on FireFox]

---

[image: Connection error on GoogleChrome]

---

I tried to reinstall certificate but Burp suit's certificate is 0 byte and I receive bellow error when I tried to figure out the cause:
[image: java.security.keystoreexception]

---

**What I tried to fix this problem?**

1. Reinstalled my Burp suit (v2021.8.4, v2021.9.1, v2 Beta, v1.7)
2. Reinstalled my Java environment (JDK -> 13.0.2, 15.0.2, 17.0.1)(JAVA -> 8 update 311)
3. Removed and reinstalled Burp suit's certificates
4. Checked Burp suit **TLS Negotiation** section
5. Reinstalled my Browsers

Comment: First, are you using www.google.com or google.com? Those are _not_ the same thing (although google.com, when you connect to it, _redirects_ to www.google.com). Make sure you are connecting to a real version of one of these systems, and which: are you in an environment like a business or university with an upstream firewall, IDS, or similar? What address(es) does `nslookup $host` give you? If you have or get OpenSSL, do `openssl s_client -connect $host:443 -showcerts` and add to your Q at least the received certs; if OpenSSL 1.1.1+ also try `-no_tls1_3`....

Comment: ... FWIW I can run Community-2021.9.1 on Oracle 17(.0.0) and connect to google.com at 142.250.80.110 without error -- but that's for my part of the world, yours may be different.

Comment: Google is an example, I have same problem on other sites when I'm useing Burp Suit.
All sites are accessible when I turn off Burp Suit's proxy.

Comment: Also I was using Burp Suit (2021.9.1) without any problem it made problems suddenly without any reasons. I have no upstream, firewall or IDS.